# Selenium Python, How to control an already opened webpage with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

"Hi, I'm trying to use selenium(Python) to perfrom some actions for me. The problem is; I want  it to control a webpage that I have already opened and signed in to. I don't want it to go through the signing in procedure again and again which is very complicated. So is there a way I can control the webpage that is already opened and not opened by the driver itself?"

Answer (score 1):

use cookies or session 
for example You can save the current cookies as a python object using pickle.

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

then get them back

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```